# how the following code works: let start = new Date().getTime(); while(newDate().getTime() - start < 5000);

Tags: javascript, date, time, while-loop, new-operator

I am unable to interpret the functionality of this code snippet. please demonstrate anyone. Thanks in advance....
since new Date is minusing from start, so it seems that it is subtracting and result is 0 and it is less than 500.....so how will the while loop works

`let start = new Date().getTime();    while(new Date().getTime() - start < 5000);`

Comment: Yes, it's less than 5000. But as the while loop runs, `newDate().getTime()` will increase, and get bigger than `start`. After 5 seconds, the difference is no longer less than 5000, so the while loop exits. In other words, the line blocks the script (and freezes the browser) for the stated amount of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet means to continue to run the next commands after 5 seconds.
new Date().getTime() returns the milliseconds of current time and `while` statement will be always true utill 5 seconds passed from the start time.

```
let start = new Date().getTime();
while(new Date().getTime() - start < 5000);
// After 5 seconds, next commands will be executed.
...
```

Comment: you mean new Date().getTime() changes with the passage of time?

Comment: why not. it will always indicate the current time's millliseconds at the time of the executing.

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

Creates a new date object with the current date and time:

```
const startDate = new Date();
```

Get the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:

```
const startTime = startDate.getTime();
```

So `new Date().getTime()` returns something like this: 1605598723149.

In the while loop we get the current the number of milliseconds until now.
And we subtract the number of milliseconds until the start (`startTime`).

```
let timeDifference = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
```

So `timeDifference` contains the number of milliseconds that have passed since the start until now.

The while loop keeps running until the timeDifference is greater than 5000 milliseconds ( = 5 seconds).

```
while(new Date().getTime() - start < 5000);
```

(We can't use a variable because the date object is static and doesn't change after declaration. So the time remains the same.)

## Code

I replaced `let` with `const` because the `start` time doesn't change.

I replaced `new Date().getTime()` with `Date.now()` because it is shorter, faster and more meaningful.

```
const start = Date.now();
while(Date.now() - start < 5000);
```

## setTimeout

If you want your code to pause for x amount of milliseconds you could use the `setTimeout()` method.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000);
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: you mean new Date().getTime() changes with the passage of time?

Comment: your answer helped me alot. Thanks